# Could not resolve module ' ' relative to ' ' Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular7

I am new to angular 7 and have trying to implement lazy loading.
After did all the things I got the above issue .

Error :

**Could not resolve module ./Modules/itemmaster/itemmaster.module relative to app\Modules\initialRouting.ts**

Folder Structure :
[image]

And :

```
  {path:'Item Master',  loadChildren:'./Modules/itemmaster/itemmaster.module#ItemMaster'}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue .

Path Of InitialRouting.ts

[image]

Comment: what is the content of initialRouting.ts?

Comment: also your path contains space, usually there won't be

Comment: check your file path. It should be a step back. "../"

Comment: changed it still got the same @RezaRahmati

Comment: @Zhu post the itemmaster.module.ts here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (remove /Modules path)

```
{path:'ItemMaster',  loadChildren:'./itemmaster/itemmaster.module#ItemMasterModule'}
```

Comment: No NgModule metadata found for 'ItemMaster'. : issue @Sheik Althaf

Comment: what is the path of `initialRouting.ts`?

Comment: just change it to `loadChildren:'./itemmaster/itemmaster.module#ItemMasterModule` in the above code

Comment: updated the answer. but don't know what is the name of the class of this file `itemmaster.module`?

Comment: @Zhu  post the  `itemmaster.module.ts` here

Comment: @Zhu the `#ItemMasterModule ` part in the above code should be same name of the calss defined inside `itemmaster.module.ts` please post it here

Comment: Worked '#ItemMasterModule part in the above code should be same name of the calss defined inside ' @JoelJoseph

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
{path:'ItemMaster',  loadChildren:'../Modules/itemmaster/itemmaster.module#ItemMaster'}
```

Comment: it gives another issue as No NgModule metadata found for 'ItemMaster'. @jcuypers

Comment: Well possible, but without posting it we wouldn't know what it could be :)   this command should be ok now.  pls post all your relevant code.